# How to do side filling of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

We need to detect the ground using simple filling starting from the bottom of the image shown below. Any suggestions?
[image: Original image]

This codes what I have done so far,

```
rgb=imread('obstacle_scene_1.jpg'); 
figure, imshow(rgb);
rgbImage = imread('obstacle_scene_1.jpg');
hsvInt = rgb2hsv(rgbImage);
hsvDouble = rgb2hsv(double(rgbImage));
figure, imshow(hsvInt);
figure, imshow(hsvDouble);
level = graythresh(hsvInt);
bw = im2bw(hsvInt,level);
bw = bwareaopen(bw, 50);
figure, imshow(bw)
```

what I want is
[image]

Comment: why dont you use matlab for that - you 'll be done in a jiff

Comment: Doesn't this seems like matlab codes for u ?

Comment: If this question is about matlab, please tag it as such. The code could be pretty much any language.

Comment: you can use graphcuts constraining the top and the obstacles top "background" and the bottom to "foreground" and let graphcut label the rest of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [GraphCut](https://github.com/shaibagon/GCMex), constraining the top and the obstacles to "background" and the bottom to "foreground":

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJQBP.jpg');
bw = img(4:243,6:325,1) > 128 ;
sz = size(bw);
```

Create pixel-wise tendency not to belong to background, stronger tendency at the bottom

```
bgp = linspace(1,0,sz(1))'*ones(1,sz(2));
```

Constrain the last row not to belong to background

```
bgp(end,:) = 1000.*(1-bw(end,:));
```

Constraint top row and obstacles not to belong to "foreground":

```
fgp = 1000.*bw; 
fgp(1,:) = 1000;
```

Create the graph (using [`sparse_adj_matrix`](https://github.com/shaibagon/GCMex/blob/master/sparse_adj_matrix.m)):

```
[ii jj] = sparse_adj_matrix(sz, 1, 1);
sel = ii<jj;
ii=ii(sel);
jj=jj(sel);
W = sparse(ii, jj, double(bw(ii)==bw(jj)), numel(bw), numel(bw));
```

Using `GraphCut` to split the image:

```
gch = GraphCut('open',[bgp(:) fgp(:)]', 500*[0 1; 1 0], W+W' );
[gch L] = GraphCut('expand', gch);
gch = GraphCut('close', gch);
```

Resulting with:

```
L = reshape(L, sz);
```

[image]